# How to use pre-populated db in windows phone 7?

Tags: sql, windows-phone-7, sql-server-ce

There is documentation stuff to create a db and SQL to LINQ. I have searched but couldn't find how to use/query a local .sdf file.

Kindly provide me any such links that help to query and use myDB.sdf.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See this blog post: http://erikej.blogspot.com/2012/01/windows-phone-local-database-tip.html

and this: http://erikej.blogspot.com/2011/06/sql-server-compact-toolbox-22visual.html